# ExtJS collapsible panel in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, extjs

I have a collapsible panel and when I open it in IE (v 11)/Edge, it collapses again. The code is working fine in Chrome, Firefox.

I created a sample, you can try in [sencha fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#home):

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
        this.container = new Ext.panel.Panel({
            width: '100%',
            height: 500,
            title: 'Main',
            layout: 'border',
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });

        this.container.add({
            xtype:'panel',
            region: 'east',
            width: 300,
            collapsible: true,
            collapsed: true,
            title: 'Collapsible'
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I add something on the `'center'` region, it works fine (also gives a JS error while `center` is undefined)

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function() {
        this.container = new Ext.panel.Panel({
            width: '100%',
            height: 500,
            title: 'Main',
            layout: 'border',
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });

        this.container.add({
            xtype: 'panel',
            region: 'center',
            title: 'Center',
        });

        this.container.add({
            xtype: 'panel',
            region: 'east',
            width: 300,
            collapsible: true,
            collapsed: true,
            title: 'Collapsible'
        });

    }
});
```

**UPDATE**

By overriding `Ext.panel.Panel`'s `placeholderExpand` function and replacing the `center.hidden = false;` row with `center && center.hidden = false;` the problem is resolved. (Maybe they forgot to check, where hidden is set to true, there is a check)

Comment: This exact thing is covered in the docs: "Any Container using the Border layout must have a child item with region:'center'. The child item in the center region will always be resized to fill the remaining space not used by the other regions in the layout." http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.Border

Comment: Ok, but I think also this must be handled to not to throw an exception, when is not used properly. Maybe showing a warning...